# Auto-enumeration in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, enums

I want to create C type enumerations, values automatically starting from 0.
What is wrong with the following code?

```
function ArrayToEnum(arr)
{
    var len = arr.lenght;
    en = {};
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        en[arr[i]]=i;
    return en;
}

a=['foo','bar'];
b=ArrayToEnum(arr);
console.debug(b.foo);

> Undefined
```

I expect it to print 0 but instead(at least in Chromium 9.0) this is undefined. If instead of calling the function, I apply the body directly, it works:

```
var l=a.length;
for(i=0;i<l;i++) b[a[i]]=i;
console.debug(b.foo);

> 0
```

What is wrong with the function?

Comment: You misspelled `length` in the 3rd line of your code. Does that error exist in your actual code as well? Also - what's the point of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's your actual code, "length" is misspelled as "lenght" in the third line:

```
 var len = arr.lenght;
```

I'd expect that to compile, but it would set `len` equal to `undefined`, which would prevent your loop body from executing at all. That would result in `arr.foo` a.k.a. `arr["foo"]` being `undefined`, as you're seeing in your output.

Also you're passing `"arr"` to `ArrayToEnum()` when your array in the previous line is called `a`, not `arr`.

The common theme here is that when you start talking about a variable you haven't defined yet. JavaScript "helpfully" defines it instead of telling you it doesn't exist yet.

I tried it in the Chrome JS console, and I got "reference error" until I fixed the "a"/"arr" problem. Once that was fixed, I got "undefined" as you describe.

When I fixed "lenght", bingo, it prints "0".

Comment: "a"/"arr" is copy/paste error, it is correct in the source, but damn i misspelled length. thanks.